# relocation truncated to fit (in arm64 baremetal program)

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm64, bare-metal

In my aarch64 baremetal program, this line causes an error.

```
printf("axpu_kernel_binary = %p, axpu_kernel_binary_len = %x\n", axpu_kernel_binary, axpu_kernel_binary_len);
```

By the linker script, the .axpudata_kernel_binary section is located at 0x100a00000 and the axpu_kernel_binary which is an address was given a section attribute for .axpudata_kernel_binary section. So the array sits at 0x100a00000 (which is above 4GB, needing more than 32 bits address).
The error message during the compile/link is like this.

> /baremetal_bm.c:179:(.text.startup+0x8c): relocation truncated to fit:
> R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `axpu_kernel_binary' defined
> in .axpudata_kernel_binary section in aarch64/cvp_earth/telechips_baremetal/baremetal_bm.o

Is it because I didn't specify the amount of memory in the linker script? (I tried searching the GNU ld manual for this error and found for two architectures there is --relax option to enable trampolin for long jump but not for arm64).

Comment: This sounds like "pointer difference is too big to be encoded as ADRP instruction". Is your bare metal binary loaded at address 0x0?

Comment: @Siguza Hi, yes I guess so. The program is loaded at 0x80000000. So the difference is 0x1_00a00000 - (approx) 0x80000000 = (approx. 0x80a00000).

Comment: Hmm, that should be fine though. That's an offset of less than 4GB.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with source core, linker script, and exact command line.